# Where are macros stored?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

If I use macros in my C code, such as

```
#define var 10
```

then where exactly are the stored in the space allocated to the process by the kernel?
In heap or BSS or global data? Or is it just a text replacement for var in one of the compiler passes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.
the last one

just a text replacement

It is performed by a preprocessing pass.
Some good details can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Comment: I don't think text replacement is quite fair. It can work with parameter lists and such.

Comment: Yes.  Macros are useful for many things.  The op is a bit fuzzy about the cpp pass.  Text replacement is what happens.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: The preprocessor is complicated, but it still just does a text to text conversion. For example, in unix systems its possible to run the preprocessor separately from the compiler and you can even use the C preprocessor for some non-C files.

Comment: @AndrewWhite: text replacement is fairly fair. For macros with parameter lists, the rules to work out from the macro arguments what text is inserted in place of the macro invocation can be reasonably complicated, but fundamentally all macro-expansion does is replace one sequence of preprocessor tokens with another (which is computed at preprocessing-time from the first sequence, if there are arguments).

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessor directives like `#define` are replaced with the corresponding text during the preprocessing phase of compilation, and are (almost) never represented in the final executable.

Answer (score 4):

"Macros" are a "compile time thing".

It just "replaces the text" that the compiler sees - before it compiles.

The result (in the compiled code) can be a set of operations ... a data declaration ... or nothing at all.

But the "macro" itself is Ancient History after the preprocessor finishes, and before compilation actually begins.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are merely text replacements. When substituted, these become a part of the code and are thus stored in CODE SEGMENT.

Answer (score 1):

It's an instruction to the compiler, and thus is stored in tables in the compiler's process space, not your code's space .

Comment: The compiler never sees it.  The preprocessor pass eats it.

Comment: Upvoted answer and comment b/c technically speaking, the  comment is correct, but practically speaking, the mere user does not see a distinction between the two. Build is normally done with a single commend, where the preprocessing is implied.